# ClassNotFoundException when I run my own code on Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have managed to run hadoop examples grep, wordcount... however I am finding some hard time trying to get my own code to run...
This is what I have done;

I copied the grep code from the examples jar and made my own changes to it. I compiled it using the command javac; and I could see in the folder I specified the hierarchy  "org/apache/hadoop/examples/filename.class "

I then packed it (the folder) into a jar; in it now is org/apache/.....
Now when I ran the command "bin/hadoop jar folder.jar filename input output " 
I keep on getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:....
```

any ideas? or guidance?

Comment: can you post the full stack trace, and a listing of the jar file contents (jar -tvf folder.jar)

Comment: When I executed the jar -tvf folder.jar command i got this line
"3503 Tue Mar 27 19:29:30 GST 2012 org/apache/hadoop/examples/Grep.class"

Comment: and this is the trace:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: grep
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:149)

Comment: in future, edit your post and paste these additions into the question itself, makes it easier to read / format etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check you are running the command with the fully qualified class name of grep:

```
hadoop jar folder.jar org.apache.hadoop.examples.Grep ..other_args..
```

Comment: Much obliged, It worked; may I ask why I had to specify the whole class name? whilst in the hadoop ready examples we did not need to?

Comment: It may have been that the hadoop examples jar has an executable jar (main class specified in the manifest) which interprets the first argument and delegates to the appropriate class - you'll need to look in the source to confirm

Answer (score 0):

to make this work I had to add to conf/hadoop-env.sh and my classpath the following:

- export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/latest
- export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/lib/hadoop
- export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce
- export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
- export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs
- export HADOOP_YARN_HOME=/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn
- export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
- export YARN_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_CONF_DIR
- export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME:$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME:$HADOOP_YARN_HOME:$HADOOP_HOME:$HADOOP_CONF_DIR:$YARN_CONF_DIR:$JSVC_HOME